# How to obtain mathematical expectation with the vector as random variable?

Tags: pr.probability, matrices, stochastic-processes

In my study, I wish to get the mathematical expectation for the term below. The vector $\boldsymbol{z} \in \mathcal{C}^{N\times1}$ and $\boldsymbol z \sim \mathcal{CN}\left(\boldsymbol{0},\boldsymbol{I_N}\right)$. How to solve the below term?

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}_{\boldsymbol{z}}\left[\frac{{\boldsymbol{z}}{\boldsymbol{z}}^H}{1+{\boldsymbol{z}}^H{\boldsymbol{Q}}{\boldsymbol{z}}}\right]
\end{equation}
where the fixed $\boldsymbol{Q} \in \mathcal{C}^{N\times N}$ and superscript $H$ stands for the conjugate transpose.

By the way, which field does this type of problem belong to? Could you recommend several books about this field to me? Thank you!

Comment: let me assume that $Q$ is Hermitian; because of the isotropy of the distribution of $z$ you can then assume without loss of generality that $Q$ is diagonal, with real elements $q_n$ on the diagonal; then you can apply results for the chi-squared distribution, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/72479/generic-sum-of-gamma-random-variables